# Using LINQ to update a product list with rank

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of products:

```
IQueryable<Product> list = _ProductRepository.GetAll();
```

The column Product.Clicks corresponds to the number of times the product has been viewed.

I want to update this list of products and update the column Product.Rank using a ranking such as this:

```
SELECT
    ProductId,
    Name,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Clicks DESC) [Rank],
    Clicks
FROM
    Product
WHERE
    Clicks > 0
```

What is the most efficient way using LINQ to do this? Is there a way to do a direct update, rather than querying the products and enumerating them? This will run as a batch job on a weekly basis.

**UPDATE:
It appears that many people have suggested that a SQL SP batch job would be the best way forward here. Points go to the person that suggests such a query.**

UPDATE: Answer as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRank 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH RankValues AS
    (SELECT [ProductId], [Clicks], [Rank],
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Clicks] DESC) AS [NewRank]
    FROM [Product])
    UPDATE [RankValues]
    SET [Rank] = [NewRank]
    WHERE Clicks > 0
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only just getting into LINQ so apologies, but why involve LINQ?

If I was looking at this problem the most efficient way would be to wrap it up in a stored proc and leave it for the server to do for you as an automated job.

Comment: I'm implementing it as suggested. So the points go to CResults.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using linq-to-sql. I would recommend using a stored procedure to do that job. When creating your DataContext, just drag your stored procedure to the methods window.

If you, for some reason, cannot use a stored procedure, linq-to-sql has an [ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspxq) method which you can use if you want to do a 'direct update' and don't want to fetch all records and then update them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer that question one would have to know how your repository is implemented (linq to sql, entity framework, custom implementation, ...). For Ling to sql there is an [ExecuteQuery method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspxq).

Depending on your repository you could also use a stored procedure to do the updating for you.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed w/ the comments thus far.  It seems like a database maintenance task, frankly, which can and shoudl be done as a batch job inside the SQL Server.  I wouldn't even involve Linq To SQL unless you need to explicitly call it from inside the app occasionally.  If that *is* the case, then you can still do what I said, but then also do as others have said and add it as a method on your datacontext.

Comment: Any suggestions how the update statement should look for this?

Comment: What you had in your select statement should work fine on the right side of the update query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single query to update Rank field with Calculated Rank using function Rank(), I think you have to create a View like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [vwProductWithRank]
AS
SELECT     ProductID, Rank, Rank() Over (Order by [Clicks]) [CalculatedRank]
FROM         Product
```

It is an updateable View and you can update it like this in your SP:

```
UPDATE vwProductWithRank Set [Rank] = [CalculatedRank]
```